# how to display data to ejs from API (express js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Using express js, i want to render json that has been produced by my to ejs file.

here is my controller that produce json

```
const getAllQuotes = asyncWrapper(async (req, res) => {
  const quotes = await qSchema.find({});
  res.status(200).json({ quotes });
});
```

I want to pass the JSON from controller to my router below, then what my router does is bring the data and show the data to admin page

```
adminRoute.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  //what should i type here?
        res.render("admin")
})
```

or maybe my question is about how the data can be thrown/passed in between js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make HTTP requests from your server back to your server.

You have a function that gets your data. Use that function.

```
adminRoute.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const quotes = await qSchema.find({});
    res.render("admin", { quotes });
})
```

Comment: I understand now, or it might be better if my router do this -> adminRoute.get('/').get(getAllQuotes); and then do fetch('') at the frontend. thankyou for the answer.